# Opening a password protected PDF document with pdf2john

Tags: password-cracking, pdf

When I try to open the document with a reader I get prompted for a password.

I tried pdf2john:

```
root@kali:~# ./pdf2john.py test.pdf > hash.txt
test.pdf : File not encrypted
```

Is pdf2john only for older versions of PDF files? How would one go about finding out more about this file and the encryption? Assuming it's AES-256, what can I use in conjunction with a password list to try and crack it?

Comment: There are online crackers, or do you want some sort of brute force offline software?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, the online stuff that I ran across is usually for removing owner passwords, or user passwords that use RC4. In other words I don't really know what the next step would be to try and figure out the password or view the document.